# How to fix `TypeError: Illegal Invocation` on an XMLHttpRequest wrapped in an ES6 Proxy

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, es6-proxy

I'm writing a proxy for `XMLHttpRequest`s, to force them to return a specific status code. I'm able to run functions on proxy, but setting fails with a TypeError: `Illegal Invocation`. In the example below, this happens on the line `oReq.responseType = "json";`. It works if that line is removed, but I need to be able to set the the XHR's properties.

```js
XMLHttpRequest = new Proxy(XMLHttpRequest, {
  construct:function(t,a){
    const req = new t();
    return new Proxy(req, {
      get:function(o,p){
        if(p=='status')return 9001
        return typeof o[p] == 'function'?o[p].bind(o):o[p]
      },
      set: function(target, prop, value, receiver) {
        Reflect.set(target, prop, value, receiver)
        return true;
      },
    })
  }
})

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
oReq.addEventListener("error", transferComplete);

oReq.open("GET", "https://blossom-emery.glitch.me/yo.json");
oReq.responseType = "json"; // TypeError: Illegal Invocation
oReq.send()

console.log(oReq)

function transferComplete(evt) {
  console.log(evt);
  console.log(oReq.status,oReq.response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For native methods like those on `XMLHttpRequest`, you can't use the proxy as the receiver, so you'd have to use `Reflect.set(target, prop, value, target)` (or omit the receiver argument). You could also simply use `target[prop] = value` here. Likewise with `Reflect.get`, which you've already opted to use `target[prop]` instead.